# Can a javascript closure function act as a callback?

Tags: javascript

I registered a callback `function(abc)` for a `forEach` call. The function `abc` is defined as a closure and it seems it doesn't get called. I would really appreciate to know more about this.

Code:

```
function xyz(array)
{
  // do something

  function abc(value,index,origin_array){
    // do something
  }

  array.forEach(abc);

  //other stuff
}
```

Comment: Works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/sp20rdzv/

Comment: you can do that by call a function inside of other function

Comment: follow-up question :can you guys step into the closure function?

Comment: You should give a complete, runnable example that reproduces your problem. Currently, you don't call `xyz` (so we don't know what the value of `array` is). Other than that, your code looks perfectly fine, so it's not possible to give you an answer.

Comment: You need to add MCVE: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, FWIW `array.forEach` is not compatible with IE8 if perhaps that is where you are testing this.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @gfullam you saved my day.How can I accept your answer now?

Comment: Console would have done that away faster ... It's there, why not to use it?

Comment: `abc` is not a closure except in the most narrow sense of the term, because it does not close over any variables in the outside scope. Even if it were, it would work fine as a callback.

Comment: @torazaburo I am using it to access some variables in the xyz scope but didn't place them. Again, my bad.

Comment: @radu I've posted my comments as an answer below. I'm glad that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A minimal, complete, and verifiable example

This works in modern browsers, but for what it's worth, [`array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) [is not compatible with IE8 and older](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility), if perhaps that is where you are testing this.

For legacy browser compatibility, use a standard [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop instead.

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];

function xyz(array) {
  console.log(array);
  
  function abc(value, index, origin_array){
    console.log(value);
  }

  array.forEach(abc);
}

xyz(numbers);
```

```html
<p>Open your development console.</p>
```